# php the date is always 1970-01-01 and 2018-08-31 after inserting to my database

Tags: php, date, mysqli

Good day! Im trying to insert date to a mysql table. The table I created is as fallow:[image: Table]

I am inserting the data with the following function statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['setSchedule'])) {
            $data->set_Schedule($test, $conn);
            echo"<script>location.replace('EvaluationSchedule.php');</script>";
        }
```

My sql insert fuction to insert the dateFrom and dateTo:

```
function set_Schedule($test, $conn){
            $setSchedule = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['setSchedule']));
            $lastSchedule = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['lastSchedule']));

            $studentLimit = $_POST['studentLimit'];

            $q = "INSERT INTO evaluation VALUES(null, ?,?,?) ";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $setSchedule, $lastSchedule,$studentLimit);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

After when I insert the date value are always 1970-01-01 and 2018-08-31:
[image: Table values]

Here's my form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8">Set Evaluation:
                                <input class="form-control col-sm-8" type="date" id="datepicker" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="setSchedule" autocomplete="off">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8">Last Evaluation:
                                <input class="form-control col-sm-8" type="date" id="datepicker1" placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="lastSchedule" autocomplete="off">
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-8">Student limit:
                                <input class="form-control col-sm-8" type="text"  placeholder="Enter Student ID" name="studentLimit" autocomplete="off">
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="setSchedule"   id="demoNotify""><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="EvaluationSchedule.php"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-times-circle"></i>Back</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I am a novice in SQL and learning now. Could anyone shed some light.. what it is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just as an observation: Why not instead of echoing a script with location.replace not use pure php: header("location:EvaluationSchedule.php")?;

Comment: Please don't add all of the corrections to your original code, this makes it difficult for future readers to understand the problem and the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that on your submit button, you are using `name="setSchedule"`, so it will overwrite the one in your first date field. And cause an invalid date.

Checking the value of `$_POST` would have shown this.